# Device communication using MQTT

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, communication

I plan to use MQTT to provide 2 way data exchange between a PC and Raspberry Pi on the same network. I know how MQTT works in terms of subscribe/publish and topics. What I am a little unsure about is whether I need 1 or 2 brokers?

As I want to provide 2 way communication do I need a broker on the PC and Raspberry Pi or do I only need one and have a client on each?

Comment: 1 broker and 2 clients (one on PC and one on the Pi) is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is a hub/spoke protocol

Clients connect to a single broker, where they publish messages to topics and subscribe to those topics to receive messages.

There is no direct communication between 2 clients, just messages published to the broker and the broker then distributes those messages to any subscribed clients.

There is no need for more than one broker in most cases.